# Error when sorting rows in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, tablecellrenderer, tablerowsorter

I'm trying to set a `RowSorter` on my Jtable, I used the method `setAutoCreateRowSorter(Boolean b)` to sort the rows

```
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

But when I make the table as `rawSorted`, I get a strange error!

The conflict is visible when I want to delete a line, I used `fireTableRowsDeleted()`.

```
int raw = table.getSelectedRow();  // the index of raw that i want to delete it
System.out.println(raw);
model.delte_raw(raw); // model is my table model

public void delte_raw(int raw)
         {
             if (!ls.isEmpty()) {
         this.fireTableRowsDeleted(raw+1, raw);
         ls.remove(raw);
         }
```

I want to show you what result return the code as above in 2 cases:

### Case 1:

When I make my table as not rawsorted:

```
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);
```

when I delete a line, it all works successfully.

### Case 2:

When I make my table as rawsorted:

```
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

when I delete a line, I get the error as below:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid range
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.checkAgainstModel(DefaultRowSorter.java:921)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.rowsDeleted(DefaultRowSorter.java:878)
    at javax.swing.JTable.notifySorter(JTable.java:4277)
    at javax.swing.JTable.sortedTableChanged(JTable.java:4121)
    at javax.swing.JTable.tableChanged(JTable.java:4398)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:296)
    at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableRowsDeleted(AbstractTableModel.java:261)
```

I think that the error is in my defaultRowSorter, so I defined my specific `cellRenderer` as below:

```
//    final TableCellRenderer r = table.getTableHeader().getDefaultRenderer();
//TableCellRenderer wrapper = new TableCellRenderer() {
//            private Icon ascendingIcon = new ImageIcon("images/e.png");
//            private Icon descendingIcon = new ImageIcon("images/e.png");
//
//    @Override
//    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
//            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
//            int row, int column) 
//    {
//        Component comp = r.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, 
//            hasFocus, row, column);
//        if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
//            JLabel label = (JLabel) comp;
//            label.setIcon(getSortIcon(table, column));
//        }
//        return comp;
//    }
//
//    /**
//     * Implements the logic to choose the appropriate icon.
//     */
//    private Icon getSortIcon(JTable table, int column) {
//        SortOrder sortOrder = getColumnSortOrder(table, column);
//        if (SortOrder.UNSORTED == sortOrder) {
//            return null;
//        }
//        return SortOrder.ASCENDING == sortOrder ? ascendingIcon : descendingIcon;
//    }
//
//    private SortOrder getColumnSortOrder(JTable table, int column) {
//        if (table == null || table.getRowSorter() == null) {
//            return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
//        }
//        List<? extends RowSorter.SortKey> keys = table.getRowSorter().getSortKeys();
//        if (keys.size() > 0) {
//                    RowSorter.SortKey key = keys.get(0);
//            if (key.getColumn() == table.convertColumnIndexToModel(column)) {
//                return key.getSortOrder();
//            }
//        }
//        return SortOrder.UNSORTED;
//    }
//
//};
//table.getTableHeader().setDefaultRenderer(wrapper);
```

But again, the same error!

Why do I get this error? I googled it a lot, but either I used the wrong keywords or there are no simple solutions on the internet.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  What's with the commented code?  It sure does not assist formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your table model:

```
public void delte_raw(int raw) {
    if (!ls.isEmpty()) {
        this.fireTableRowsDeleted(raw+1, raw); // why raw+1 ???
        ls.remove(raw);
    }
}
```

As your table model extends from `AbstractTableModel` and looking at [fireTableRowsDeleted(int firstRow, int lastRow)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsDeleted%28int,%20int%29) javadoc:

> Notifies all listeners that rows in the range `[firstRow, lastRow]`,
>   inclusive, have been deleted.

So it should be:

```
public void delte_raw(int raw) {
    if (!ls.isEmpty()) {            
        ls.remove(raw); // remove the row index from the List and then fire the event
        fireTableRowsDeleted(raw, raw);
    }
}
```

**Knowing the exception source:** looking at `DefaultRowSorter.checkAgainstModel(int firstRow, int endRow)` implementation:

```
private void checkAgainstModel(int firstRow, int endRow) {
    if (firstRow > endRow || firstRow < 0 || endRow < 0 ||
            firstRow > modelRowCount) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid range");
    }
}
```

As you can see, calling this method with `[raw+1,raw]` range causes an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**Edit**

As @mKorbel masterfully points out, I've totally overlooked this:

```
int raw = table.getSelectedRow();  // this is the index in the view
model.delte_raw(raw); // convert raw in the right model index is needed
```

You need to convert `raw` in the right model index. Otherwise it can cause side effects since in a sorted table is most likely the selected index in the view be different than its related model's index:

```
int raw = table.getSelectedRow();  // this is the index in the view
model.delte_raw(table.convertRowIndexToModel(raw)); // perfect
```

See [JTable.convertRowIndexToModel(int viewRowIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29)

Comment: you are right , tthe error is abot interval [firatraw,lastraw] !!

Comment: not, not, can caused side veffects, have to convert View Index To Model, clearly  described in Official Oracle tutorial with bold font in part Sorting and Filtering

Comment: @mKorbel you're right. I've totally overlooked that. Thanks! See updated answer.

Comment: @Fadel please read mKorbel's comment and see updated answer :)

Comment: Dears ... dic19 & @mkorbel .... rly big big big thanks for youuuuu :) :) :) now it worked and all its okayyy !!!!!!!